# Compute accordance of column values grouped by another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame with a column of IDs spanning multiple rows (`col_id`) and another column of assessments for this row (`col_assessment`), like so:

```
df <- data.frame(col_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                 col_assessment = c("Pos", "Pos", "Neu", "Neu", "Neg", "Neu", "Pos", "Neu", "Neg"))
```

I now want to calculate how much the assessment is in accordance for each row. (I.e. how many of the assessments are the same per ID. For this, I have the following function. (I do not have to use this function and am also open to other solutions.)

```
compute_ICR <- function(coding_values){
      ### takes in list of coding values and returns number of the share of agreement (up to 1 if all are in agreement)
      most_common_value <- coding_values %>% table() %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% magrittr::extract(1) %>% names()

      share_accordance <- length(which(coding_values == most_common_value)) / coding_values %>% nrow()

      # number of matching, most common values divided by number of total values
      return(share_accordance)
      }
```

I would now like to apply this to `df` by group of `col_id`, like so (not working pseudo-code!)

```
df %>% group_by(col_id) %>% summarize(share_accordance = compute_ICR(df$col_assessment))
```

This should give me the following data frame for the above example:

```
data.frame(col_id = c(1,2,3), share_accordance = c(.6667, 1, .333))
```

Can someone point out how to achieve this result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `col_id = 2` be .667 as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the function to -

```
compute_ICR <- function(x){
  sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1]/length(x)
}
```

and apply it for each `ID` .

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(col_id) %>% 
  summarize(share_accordance = compute_ICR(col_assessment))

#  col_id share_accordance
#   <dbl>            <dbl>
#1      1            0.667
#2      2            0.667
#3      3            0.333
```

Or in base R -

```
aggregate(col_assessment~col_id, df, compute_ICR)
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question you want the largest proportion of answers per ID? The code below will give this answer independent of the number of possible values for `col_assessment`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(col_id) %>% 
  summarise(prop = max(prop.table(table(col_assessment))))
```

Returns:

> ```
>   col_id prop
>    <dbl> <dbl>
> 1      1 0.667
> 2      2 0.667
> 3      3 0.333
> ```